# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'

Tags: typescript, observable

I've been scouring the web for a solution to this, what probably is, a minor problem.

My function on one ts. file:

```
public getHelpContent(question: string[]) {

  let theHelp: any[] = [];
  theHelp = this.mssqlService.getTheHelpAnswer(question);
  console.log("THE HELP:", theHelp);
  this.commentContent = theHelp ;

  let foundContent: any[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.commentContent.length; i++) {
    let hitContent: string[];
    hitContent = this.searchHelpItem(question, this.commentContent[i]);
    if (hitContent) {
      foundContent.push(hitContent);
    }
  }

  return theHelp;

}
```

The function on the mssql-service.ts file

```
getTheHelpAnswer(jsonObj: any): any {
  let body = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
  console.log("BODY VAR: ", body);
  return this.http
    .post<any>(`${this.urlLocation}notification/TheHelp`, body)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and the HANDLE ERROR for prosperity...

```
private handleError(error: Response | any) {

  let errMsg: string;
  if (error instanceof Response) {
    const body = error || '';
    const err = JSON.stringify(body);
    errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
  } else {
    errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
  }
  console.error(errMsg);
  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
```

}

the ERROR I GET on compile is this:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'
```

When I change the :any here from:

```
getTheHelpAnswer(jsonObj: any): any {
```

to

```
getTheHelpAnswer(jsonObj: any): Observable<any> { ...
```

this is the error I get:

```
ERROR in src/app/app-help-state-machine.ts(364,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'.
src/app/app-help-state-machine.ts(371,50): error TS2345: 
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

UPDATE1:

I forgot to add the signature of the FUNCTION

```
public getHelpContent(question: string[]): any[] { ...
```

But I still get this...

```
ERROR in src/app/app-help-state-machine.ts(364,5): error TS2322: Type 
'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
      Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'.
src/app/app-help-state-machine.ts(371,50): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
```

UPDATE 2:

I figured it out...

See solution where I answered my own question....

Comment: the only typisation for String[] I see is  `let hitContent: string[];
    hitContent = this.searchHelpItem(question, this.commentContent[i]);`  so IM asuming the searchHelpItem method returns a String instead of an array

Comment: `this.searchHelpItem` probably returns a string, not a string array

Comment: DARN IT, the signature should be: public getHelpContent(question: string[]): any[] {... I forgot the :any[] but I still get the same errors... see UPDATE1:

Comment: Stefan, Jonathan:  do you have any ideas?  I really need to get over this blocker.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the solution:**

**I changed this function:**

```
public getHelpContent(question: string[]) {

  let theHelp: any[] = [];
  theHelp = this.mssqlService.getTheHelpAnswer(question);
  console.log("THE HELP:", theHelp);
  this.commentContent = theHelp ;

  let foundContent: any[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.commentContent.length; i++) {
    let hitContent: string[];
    hitContent = this.searchHelpItem(question, this.commentContent[i]);
    if (hitContent) {
      foundContent.push(hitContent);
    }
  }

  return theHelp;

}
```

**to this:**

```
public getHelpContent(question: string[]): string[] {

  const questionInfo = {
    "question": question
  }

  let theHelp = this.mssqlService.getTheHelpAnswer(questionInfo, question);
  console.log("THE HELP:", theHelp);

//Commented this out... as it caused the issue

//    this.commentContent = theHelp;
//
//    let foundContent: any[] = [];
//    for (let i = 0; i < this.commentContent.length; i++) {
//      let hitContent: string[];
//      hitContent = this.searchHelpItem(question, this.commentContent[i]);
//      if (hitContent) {
//        foundContent.push(hitContent);
//      }
//    }

  return lucyHelp;

}
```

**and on the mssql-connect.service.ts file, the receiving function**

**Changing this:**

```
getTheHelpAnswer(jsonObj: any): any {
   let body = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
   console.log("BODY VAR: ", body);
   return this.http
       .post<any>(`${this.urlLocation}notification/TheHelp`, body)
       .map((response: Response) => response.json())
       .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**to this...**

```
getTheHelpAnswer(jsonObj: any, question: string[]): string[] {
   let body = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
   console.log("BODY VAR: ", body);

   let result = this.http
     .post<any>(`${this.urlLocation}notification/TheHelp${question}`, body)
     .map((response: Response) => response.json())
     .catch(this.handleError);

   console.log("RESULT FROM HTTP: ", result);

  return result ;
}
```